# How could I add information if I did not find certain data from my database?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using pandas package to filter out my needed information from a certain database based on their name. But I just simply know how to filter them out rather than add extra information to the list in my result.

I give a list which I want to retrieve information based on them:

```
import pandas

require_list = []
with open('require.csv') as fo:
    for line in fo:
        require_list.append(line.strip())

#Then I see,
id 
cat
elephant          
dog           # I have elephant in my list.
```

Then I start to read data from my database by pandas:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("require_database.csv")

  id        kg    
0 squirrel  0.1
1 horse     80
2 cat       7
3 bee       0.03      
4 dog       12 
5 goldfish  0.08      # Unfortunately I do not have data for elephant.
```

Then I use "isin" function to retrieve data based on my given title...

```
data_list = data[data['id'].isin(require_list)]
print data_list

# I'd like to get something like below....
 id        kg
 cat       7
 elephant  null   # Add "null" behind the elephant..
 dog       12     # Order is the same as my given list.
```

My question is how could I add information such as "null" behind the animal that I do not have data for them?  And the order in my result should be the same as my list.  Does anyone know how to achieve this by pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a df from your list and then perform a [left](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) style [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) with your database df this will add the values where they exist and put nan where they don't:

```
In [52]:

animal_list=['cat','elephant','dog']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':animal_list})
df
Out[52]:
         id
0       cat
1  elephant
2       dog

df1
Out[51]:
         id     kg
0  squirrel   0.10
1     horse  80.00
2       cat   7.00
3       bee   0.03
4       dog  12.00
5  goldfish   0.08
In [50]:

df.merge(df1, on='id', how='left')
Out[50]:
         id  kg
0       cat   7
1  elephant NaN
2       dog  12
```

Comment: Much appreciated!!! I totally used the wrong function to deal with this issue. And when I use result.to_csv('path') to save the result, if I'd like to see "NaN" in the blank cell, do you know how to achieve that? It appears that it usually shows nothing there right?

Comment: It should read it back as nan I think, if you want to be specific then pass param `na_rep='nan'` to `df.to_csv`, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv

Comment: Sorted!! Because comment must be more than 15 characters then I typed my answer here, df.to_csv('path', na_rep = "nan"), thanks again.